# How to pass FBA credentials to a custom wcf service @ SP

Tags: wcf

I am creating a custom wcf service deployed on sharepoint. 
How to pass the current user's credentials to the service (from a web part)?
Do i have to use these helpers:
SPChannelFactoryOperations.ConfigureCredentials 
SPChannelFactoryOperations.CreateChannelActingAsLoggedOnUser

Should it be possible to get this working with oob SharePoint service factory? Or should I shift to wsHttpBinding?

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the users token to the wcf service
token of current user can be found as follows:

```
SPWeb myWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPUser user = myWeb.CurrentUser
SPUserToken token = user.UserToken
```

[SPUserToken Refrence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spusertoken_members.aspx)

Comment: I'm using windows authentication so shouldn't the user authenticate automatically?

Comment: ok i see you want to just pass his username and pass to the wcf service as parameters and not for authentication?

Comment: I'd like to authenticate the logged on user in the service. But when trying to read SPUser from SPContext.Current.Web it throws an exception for some reason. Should it work just oob in the web service (when called from a web part)?

Comment: I mean, via REST directly from the browser everything works fine and I can access the SharePoint API and the logged user's credentials (either via http or https). But when accessed via SOAP from my web part the wcf throws at SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser and authenticates as the process account the web part is running on.

Comment: what exception does it throw i do see your challange though

Comment: Hm, stupid question but how to see the detailed wcf error message? (are there other methods than modifying sharepoint web.config to enable some wcf tracing?)

Comment: Also cannot access the user credentials via OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext (although works fine via REST). The only way I seem to be able to access the client credentials is via WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() which returns the sp process account.